# read ascii file with empty entries in python

Tags: python, numpy, ascii

I have a file that looks like:

```
 145.342050   -0.906349   4915
 145.463209   -0.844225   4915
 145.502417   -0.966603
 145.582172   -0.892733   4917
 145.618846   -0.972673
 145.681139   -0.867231   4883
 145.821685   -0.846610   4883
```

I tried to use `np.genfromtxt` without success.

```
import numpy as np
a,b,c = np.genfromtxt('filename',missing_values=" ",unpack=True)
```

Anybody who knows a good way store only rows with three entries or fill empty places? I didn't manage `filling_values` of `np.genfromtxt`.

**Edit:**
This is the error python throws out:

```
Line #23 (got 2 columns instead of 3)
```

Comment: Isn't the parameter name `filling_values` instead of `fill_values`? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: @JohannesCharra Sorry it was a typo, thanks for noticing. I edited it

Comment: Is your file formatted _exactly_ as the example file, i.e. _no_ whitespace after the second column in the lines where the third column is missing? In your function call the argument `missing_values=" "` means that a single space represents a missing value. In your example file, that is _not true_, and therefore this will not work. Also, when the delimiter in your example file is 3 x space, and you don't specify this, the function will consider these spaces as _three missing values_. So if you do want to use `np.genfromtxt`, consider reformatting your file if possible.

Comment: @nordev, yes you are right, there is no delimiter after the second column when the third one is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a,b,c = np.genfromtxt('filename',missing_values=" ", filling_values = 0 ,unpack=True)
```

Comment: thx for the answer, I exactly tried this before with same negative outcome `Line #... (got 2 columns instead of 3)`